# Probability of drawing 4 aces when drawing 10 cards

Tags: probability, card-games

So I'e done a bit of searching and haven't found an answer or a source I can re-learn the probability equations so here's hoping for an answer.

I'm curious if you have a deck of 54 cards (jokers) and you draw 10 cards, what are the chances of drawing 4 aces?

What about 4 aces and 1 or 2 jokers?

Cards are not being replaced but we can assume a fresh 'perfectly' shuffled deck. The other cards do not matter.

I would appreciate the math as it would be helpful to understand how to perform this myself, it's just been ~15 years since I've needed to use any of this.

Comment: It is easiest to work with "hands" here where order within the hand is irrelevant.  There are $\binom{54}{10}$ different hands of size ten possible.  $\binom{50}{6}$ of those have all four aces (*and possibly some jokers*).  $\binom{48}{6}$ of them have four aces and no jokers, $\binom{48}{5}\cdot 2$ have four aces and one joker, and $\binom{48}{4}$ have four aces and both jokers.  Take the ratio of number of possible "desired" hands over the total number of hands possible to get the probability (*in an equiprobable setting such as this one*).

Comment: @JMoravitz, could you please post that as an answer?  Even though brief, it *does* answer the question and IMO it is more clear than the only posted answer so far.

Comment: Yeah. The other was deleted anyway. I'm just not sure how to break those down into a percentage based chance. I found it at about 2% myself but I just have no way of knowing if I'm actually correct.

Also not sure how I could apply it differently (e.g. 2 aces of the 10 cards, etc)

Comment: For the four aces, the calculation is $\frac {\binom {50}{6} }{ \binom {54}{10}}=\frac {15890700}{23930713170}=\frac {70}{105417} \sim 0.000664$

Comment: For computing these kinds of probabilities, the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) is your friend.